# Re-installing Node JS failed

Tags: node.js, npm, rhel

I am using RHEL 6.
I needed to uninstall NodeJS and install a different version of it.
I found various methods for uninstalling it and as instructed deleted all the node and npm related files.

But when i try to install it again i get the following error -

**Package nodejs-6.2.1-1nodesource.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do**

Any help ?

Comment: "as instructed" — Instructed by what? Exactly what did you do? It sounds like you found some instructions which didn't apply to your system.

Comment: This seems to me more of a "How do I use Red Hat's package management system?" question so would probably be better asked on SuperUser as it isn't really programming related.

Comment: @Quentin I removed all the node related files from /usr/local/bin and a few other folders.

Comment: Manually? When you had an RPM installed? Sounds like you did that wrong then. I've no idea how you recover when your RPM database doesn't match the files you have left.

Comment: Yes ! thanks, it was apackage management issue